# Google Text Overlapping into android GoogleMap v2

Tags: android

I am using google map v2 with markers in my android application. While clicking marker it shows popup window. Its working fine. But while  moving Google map Popup window is overlapping into "Google" text. [image]Here i no need to overlap my popup window. Any possible to remove the "Google" text.

Answer (score 0):

You may not try to hide the logo as it would violate the Google Maps API ToS

> 9.4 Attribution.
>
> (a) Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features of Google, its partners, or other third party rights holders of content indexed by Google. When Google provides this attribution, you must display it as provided through the Service or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation and may not delete or in any manner alter these trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features.

Comment: ok.. is it possible to hide a popup while overlapping with "Goolge" text in android map v2?...